# Changing an array in function doesn't change it's value in main

Tags: c, pointers

I try to fullfill a vector (which i have to allocate) with random numbers between -0.8 and 0.8. My question is why in the main function when i call the function setvector() does not return the vector and i still take the initialized with zeros? Thanks a lot. here what i did

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

void allocate(double **a, int size) {
    *a = malloc(size);
}

double setvector(double *v){
    int i, seed, send_size;

    send_size = 10;

    allocate(&v, send_size * sizeof(double)); // allocate memory for the vector
    seed = time(NULL);
    srand(seed);
    for (i = 0; i < send_size; i++)
    {
        v[i] = 1.6*((double) rand() / (double) RAND_MAX) - 0.8;
    }
    printf("Inside function the vector is:\n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf("The %d element has the random %4.2f\n", i, v[i]);
    }
    return *v;
}

int main(){
    double *v = NULL;
    setvector(v);
    printf("\nThe vector from main is:\n\n");
    printf("The 1st element of v is %4.2f\n", &v[0]);
    printf("The 1st element of v is %4.2f\n", &v[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

Here is my screen output:

> Inside function the vector is:
>
> The 0 element has the random -0.79
>   The 1 element has the random -0.34
>   The 2 element has the random 0.48
>   The 3 element has the random -0.67
>   The 4 element has the random -0.70
>   The 5 element has the random 0.61
>   The 6 element has the random -0.67
>   The 7 element has the random -0.66
>   The 8 element has the random -0.44
>   The 9 element has the random -0.36
>
> The vector from main is:
>
> The 1st element of v is 0.00
>   The 1st element of v is 0.00

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `main` you're passing the addresses of the array elements to `printf`:

```
printf("The 1st element of v is %4.2f\n",&v[0]);
printf("The 1st element of v is %4.2f\n",&v[1]);
```

That should be `printf(..., v[0]);`.

Further:

```
double setvector(double *v){
```

doesn't change `v` in `main`, so `v` remains `NULL` there. You should have `setvector` take a `double**`, like `allocate`, and pass it the address of `v`.

Comment: for me not clear yet but thanks a lot. I think is something like **argv or *argv[]

Comment: In `main`: `setvector(&v);`. The function: `double setvector(double **vec) { ... allocate(vec); ... for(...) (*vec)[i] = 1.6*...`.

Comment: the return should be return **vec;